# Oracle convert number to words in Arabic

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this code :

```
select to_Char(to_timestamp(lpad(3536,9,'0'),'FF9'),'Ffsp') from dual
```

result will be

```
Three Thousand Five Hundred Thirty-Six
```

this code problem is that it has a limitation of 8 numbers, can I make it accept more?
and then how can I display the text in Arabic?

note: I work on oracle fusion, we can not use `pl/sql` and create `pl/sql` functions

Answer (score 0):

> this code problem is that it has a limitation of 8 numbers, can I make it accept more?

Yes, split the code up into 3-digit chunks and parse each separately using your `Ffsp` method or using a similar method with the `Jsp` format model and then concatenate the 3-digit groups into a single string:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LISTAGG(
                  CASE
                  WHEN depth = 1 AND part = '0'
                  THEN 'ZERO'
                  WHEN part = '000'
                  THEN NULL
                  ELSE CASE
                       WHEN is_last = 0
                       THEN ' '
                       END || 
                       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(part, 'J'), 'JSP') ||
                       CASE depth
                       WHEN 1 THEN NULL
                       WHEN 2 THEN ' THOUSAND'
                       WHEN 3 THEN ' MILLION'
                       WHEN 4 THEN ' BILLION'
                       WHEN 5 THEN ' TRILLION'
                       WHEN 6 THEN ' QAUDRILLION'
                       WHEN 7 THEN ' QUINTILLION'
                       WHEN 8 THEN ' SEXTILLION'
                       WHEN 9 THEN ' SEPTILLION'
                       WHEN 10 THEN ' OCTILLION'
                       WHEN 11 THEN ' NONILLION'
                       WHEN 12 THEN ' DECILLION'
                       WHEN 13 THEN ' UNDECILLION'
                       WHEN 14 THEN ' DUODECILLION'
                       END
                  END,
                  NULL
                ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY depth DESC) AS words
         FROM   (
           SELECT CASE
                  WHEN 3*LEVEL > LENGTH(value)
                  THEN SUBSTR(value, 1, MOD(LENGTH(value), 3))
                  ELSE SUBSTR(value, -3*LEVEL, 3)
                  END AS part,
                  LEVEL AS depth,
                  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF AS is_last
           FROM   DUAL
           CONNECT BY 3 * LEVEL - 2 <= LENGTH(value)
         )
       );
```

---

> and then how can I display the text in Arabic?

Normally, `TO_CHAR` takes a third argument where you can specify the NLS settings for the conversion and can change the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` setting to a different langauge:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Month', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=French') AS french,
       TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Month', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Arabic') AS arabic
FROM   DUAL
```

Outputs:

| FRENCH | ARABIC |
| --- | --- |
| Février | فبراير |

But if you use the `JSP` or `Ffsp` format models then they ignore that setting and just output English:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(3245, 'J'), 'Jsp', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=French') AS french,
       TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'FFsp', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Arabic') AS arabic
FROM   DUAL
```

| FRENCH | ARABIC |
| --- | --- |
| Three Thousand Two Hundred Forty-Five | THREE HUNDRED SEVENTY-SIX MILLION SIX HUNDRED FIVE THOUSAND |

You are going to need to use a different method of translating the numbers to Arabic as the built-in methods do not, unfortunately, appear to support anything other than English.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jxC0Fz6H)